# Can i bake textures when there isn't a principled BSDF?

Tags: materials, baking

I have a material, where there isn't a principled BSDF, Can it be baked? If so, then how?
[image]

what the material looks like when it is applied to a plane
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, like any material. What are you trying to bake exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to bake the material in the pic I attached. Its a transparent material with black lines, but I don't know how to bake it because the only way I do know is when there is a principled BSDF . I'll edit my post and attach a picture of what it looks when it's applied to a plane, in case you're curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bake the output of the brick texture which is a mask for transparency.

Just plug it into an *Emission* node (or directly into the *Material Output* node. Blender will use an *Emission* node internally to convert it.) Then add an *Image Texture* node for the image to bake and select it. Choose bake type `Emit` and bake the mask. Don't forget to save the image.

The baked mask can be used for the *Mix Shader* node that you have as a replacement for the *Brick Texture* node.

Or create a new node setup with just a *Principled BSDF* node and the baked image texture. Use the image for the *Alpha* input and set *Base Color* to black (=the diffuse color).

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly, Thanks a lot Blunder :))